# How do I avoid code duplication without multiple inheritance (i.e. in java)?

Tags: java, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, extends

(I'm a novice developer still learning best practices and java - any help/direction would be appreciated, thank you!)

Suppose I have the following situation:

- `ClassA` extends abstract `ClassB` which extends abstract `ClassC`.
- `ClassD` extends abstract `ClassE` which extends abstract `ClassF`
  which extends abstract `ClassC`.

[`ClassC` is the parent class]

where `ClassA` and `ClassD` have a set of identical properties, getters, & setters.

I want to avoid that code duplication (properties,getters,setters). I also want to avoid writing different methods `doSomething(ClassA class, ...)` and `doSomething(ClassD class, ...)` that are identical in all but the argument type.

If these two classes inherited directly from `ClassC`, I'd have them extend a class that had all the getters and setters and properties, and pass that type into the method `doSomething(..)`. Since `ClassA` and `ClassD` can't extend multiple classes, what's the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Well in java you could use *interfaces*.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of why you would allow the interitance graph to get so deep?

Comment: So D is an E is a F is a C. That's a bit too much use of inheritance.

Comment: Consider using _delegation_ instead of inheritance.  That is, the relationship `A` _has a_ `B` usually can solve all the same problems that can be solved by `A` _is a_ `B` and more.

Comment: You can use composition instead of inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>First of all, let me say that it is very good when a (by their own admission) novice developer is concerned about issues of this kind. Most developers refrain from thinking, and just write lots and lots of mindless code because this is the path that they know will work, no thinking necessary. (And having to maintain all that code never seems to be much of a problem because... it lies so far in the future!)</sup>

#### Composition

The approach that most Java shops follow is to avoid inheritance, because it is too complicated, and use composition instead, which also results in lots and lots of mindless code having to be written. More often than not, this is done due to a misinterpretation of the advice that said "favor composition over inheritance" as if it said "use only composition, never use inheritance".

I do not know exactly what you are working with, so I cannot advice you to drop what you are doing and use composition instead. I will just assume you have your reasons for using inheritance, so, I will not write more about composition here; if you are interested to learn more about composition, the term "composition vs. inheritance" can easily be googled.

#### Interface inheritance

Judging by the class structure you described, you seem to be in the typical kind of situation that would greatly benefit from the use of interfaces: In Java, a class cannot extend multiple classes, but it can implement multiple interfaces.

If two interfaces both define a method like `reticulate( Spline s )`, and a class implements both of those interfaces, then it can provide a single implementation of `reticulate()`, and it will satisfy both interfaces. (The disadvantage of this is that if you want your class to provide a different implementation of `reticulate()` for each interface, you are stuck; it cannot be done.)

Furthermore, Java supports `default` methods in interfaces, which means that a certain part of the functionality you need to offer can be coded straight into the interfaces, so that implementing classes inherit this functionality from the interface and therefore do not have to re-implement it.

Comment: You might not need to avoid inheritance: Java already allows [multiple inheritance of method implementations](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/12/default-methods-in-java-8-and-multiple-inheritance/) in interfaces.

Comment: @AndersonGreen you are right, I modified my answer to take that into account.  Please let me know if you think that a better job could be done to address the issue you brought up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly but I'll give it a try. Instead of multiple abstract classes, create multiple interfaces. Then create a class that implements both interfaces. Java allows implementing multiple interfaces but not extending from multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that it might be useful to have a `ClassAD`, that extends `ClassC` and contains the methods common to `ClassA` and `ClassD.`

Another option is to create an interface `InterfaceAD` and have `ClassA` and `ClassD` implement it. Use the interface as a parameter to the functions, like `doSomething(InterfaceAD i)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
class M

    class A extends B

        inherit B's stuff

    class D extends E

        inherit E's stuff

    A b = new A();
    D d =  new D();
    // or use anonymous classes

     M has access to everything in A and D,
    therefore M has access to A and D inheritable assets.
```

Now add you common method in C class

Answer (score 0):

You should really discuss the abstract classes here. How are you going to *test* A, B, and C, D, E, and F?
That will include a lot of duplicate testcases for any method implemented by C (since it is also used by all other classes), etc.

As has been said, really discuss composition over inheritance. A might have a C, and pass through methods.  It might also have a Q, and so will D.
Both D and A can then implement the same interface (possibly also implemented by Q, although that would probably make it confusing)

Be aware, I'm not a fan of abstract classes, and prefer to use composition and/or strategies instead.